# How to access a view element from controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am building a .NET MVC application. I have an anchor tag in my view and my requirement is to assign a href to that tag from the controller's method. To be clear, in an aspx page we can create an element and give it an ID. Now from its code behind, we can access and manipulate that element by calling it by its ID name. I am trying t find out if there is a way to achieve similar behavior with MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you could do this.

You could use a view model by having your controller return the View passing an object to use as the view model:

**Controller**

```
var model = new MyModel();
model.Url = "something";
return View(model);
```

**View**

```
@model MyModel

<a href="@Model.Url"> link text </a>
```

Or you could use ViewBag:

**Controller**

```
ViewBag.Url = "something";
return View();
```

**View**

```
<a href="@ViewBag.Url"> link text </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign `href` from controller to view you can try this.

### Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Link ="www.test.com";
    return View();
}
```

### View

```
<a href="@ViewBag.Link">Click</a>
```

Here is the [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8eq7rD).

Answer (score 0):

You would only want to do this if the href is to a link to an address outside your webapp. If its in your application then you should use [Html.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) ..

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link text","ActionName","ControllerName")
```

And if you just want the link address to be set by the controller than you should put it in the ViewBag

In Controller:

```
    ViewBag.LinkAddress = "http://www.test.com"
    ViewBag.LinkText = "Go to test.com"
```

In View

```
<a href="@ViewBag.LinkAddress">@ViewBag.LinkText</a>
```

Hope that's clear.